# C# public property get accessor inaccessible from another namespace

Tags: c#, properties, public, accessor

I have tried making the field public itself; I have also tried using public get, even if, as I understand, access modifiers inside a property will only have effect if more restrictive. Yet I wasn't able to access the '**problem.Points**'(last line) property from the TestUnit. I get an "get accessor inaccessible" alert. Notice that I'm able to access it from another class in the same namespace. I must be missing something very basic here.

```
namespace Coordinates_Path
{
    public interface IProblem
    {
        abstract public List<Node> Points { get; set; }
        abstract public Object GetStartState();
        abstract public bool IsGoalState();
        abstract public Object GetSuccessor();
    }

    public class ShortestPathThroughCoordinates : IProblem
    {
        private Node startState;
        private List<Node> points;

        public List<Node> Points { get { return points; } private set; }
    //...
    //...

using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Coordinates_Path;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CoordPathTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class KruskalTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMST()
    {
        // ...

        IProblem problem = new ShortestPathThroughCoordinates("P1", coordDic);
        MSTKruskal kruskal = new MSTKruskal(problem.Points)
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message?  Is the type `Node` public, or at least visible to the test assembly?

Comment: You're. That's it. I went all around checking it, but somehow didn't notice the that **Node** wasn't public. Thanks

Comment: Made it into an answer then :-)

Comment: The code in the question doesn't compile, you can't specify abstract nor public in an interface declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at

```
public class ShortestPathThroughCoordinates : IProblem
{
    public List<Node> Points { get { return points; } private set; }
    ...
```

all referenced classes must be visible to the calling assembly.  Check to ensure that `Node` is also visible.

Comment: Note @Lasse's comment under the question that `abstract public` does not belong in the interface declaration.  The interface itself is public, and all members it implements must be implemented with the same visibility, so you do not actually specify their visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Change your interface to this:

```
public interface IProblem
{
     List<Node> Points { get; set; }
     Object GetStartState();
     bool IsGoalState();
     Object GetSuccessor();
}
```

Interfaces only define public members so you do not have to declare it. All members of an interface must be implemented so there is also no need to declare them as abstract.

Unless private List points; is set somewhere further down in the code that we can't see you are never initializing this variable so your get will be null;

Comment: The problem, as Eric mentioned, was in not declaring `Node` public. Yes, I know there is a lot of redundant declarations here, but I tried all kinds of superfluous changes. Thanks